# Aspnet cookie authentication middleware, set authenticated in first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I have an AspNet application used as an API endpoint.

There is a middleware used to retrieve a token from the headers and load the roles in a claim.

The middleware then calls SignInAsync and calls the next request delegate .

However the first request is always unauthorized and the next ones are fine.

Apparently AspNet creates the cookie but does not authenticated the user at the first request.

How is it possible to authenticate and authorize the user in the first request directly ?

Comment: Please share the relevant code and clarify more about the question, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I found a way to make it work.

I've added in the Authentication middleware after the

```
  httpContext.SignInAsync(claimsIdentity);
```

The line

```
  httpContext.User.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
```

And the user is now identified in the first request directly